# Android Studio cannot generate bundle or APK

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I have Android Studio 4.1.2 and no matter which project I try to generate a bundle for, when I select "release" and then finish, nothing happens anymore.

I've had this problem before and I had to manually generate and sign my APKs. Now the problem is back again.

Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

The release builds are signed using your private key. You can start with configuring your keystore, which will contain the K-V pair.
Refer : [Setting up key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key)

Then you can try generating the apk using that signed key.
Refer: [Generate signed APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release)

If you are facing some specific error, can you share that.

Comment: I have the keystore setted up and everything, but when I click generate, the window simply goes away and nothing happens